# Cut out unnecessary characters from pytesseract output

Tags: python, image, ocr, python-tesseract

im trying to get a list of prices from an mmorpg using pytesseract to get data as string from screenshots.

Example screenshot:

[image: Example Image]

The output from my image looks like that

> [' ', '', '      ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', '   ', '', '
> ', '    ', '  ', '', ' ', '', "eel E J Gbasce'sthiel Sateen nach", '', '     ', '', 'Ly] Preis aufsteigend', '', '[ Tternname Anzahl Preis pro Stick Zeitraum. Verkaufer', '', ' ', '', '
> ', '', ' ', '', '**Holzstock 1 149,999** 30 Tag@e) Heavend', '', '

I just want to get that **bold** section (name, amount, price) out of the output but i really dont know how to cut it out of that text mess.

Does someone got an idea how can i achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please bring some images related to this question.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what im trying to get data from. Thank you!

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method is finding **Holzstock** section of your images. It's easy, you could use advanced models like **YOLO** Or you could try it using feature description and matching by classical methods like SURF and SIFT and .... Then crop that part and feed it to **tesseract**.

This method has some benefits, for example you will find all **Holzstock** section of your images and doing OCR after that. It leads to decresing OCR error and remove unnecessary parts of text.